# how to Invoke a firebase callable function from firebase https function with authentication?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to understand how we can securely call a firebase callable function from firebase https function, Here auth is required so that callable function is not public, it should be accessible only by that https function.

Note: I am new to gcloud and firebase :(

Https Function:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as app from "firebase/app";
//import * as auth from "firebase/auth"
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "WEBAPIKEY",
authDomain: "project.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://project.firebaseio.com", // not required though
projectId: "project-id",
storageBucket: "project.appspot.com", // not required
//appId: process.env.APP_ID,  // not sure what to provide
messagingSenderId: "1234324" // default service account id
};
const firebaseApp = app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const caller = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   let messageText = "hi";
   const gfunctions = getFunctions(firebaseApp);
   const funtionB = httpsCallable(gfunctions, 'funtionB');
   funtionB({ text: messageText })
     .then((result: any) => {
      // Read result of the Cloud Function.
      console.log(result);
      response.send(result);
    });
 });
```

Callable Function:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const funtionB = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log(context.auth); // not getting anything
  /* if (!context.auth) { //trying to include this.
    return {status: "error", code: 401, message: "Not signed in"};
  } */
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve({data: "YO", input: data});
  });
});
```

Some logs, which make me to feel bad,

```
Callable request verification passed {"verifications":{"app":"MISSING","auth":"MISSING"}}
```

I am not going to user browser to consume this https function, not sure whether we can use auth check without browser.  Any way to secure this callable function ? I want to remove alluser access from principal for both the functions to make it private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this isn't possible because, as you mentioned, the auth checks cannot be done without the browser, also the [`httpsCallable`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.functions.HttpsCallable) interface does not allow the context to be forced by passing as a parameter.

I would say that the best option would be to convert your Callable Function into an Http Function where you can implement your own authentication checks, this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) may be useful for that.